# Why view hierarchy get lost when map marker shows callout view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

I'm using MapKit with Objective-C, I have my Map View Controller and a Bottom Sheet View Controller, both are two different ViewController's, the thing is that I use the bottom view controller in order to start or stop sharing user's location. The first time you enter the map the bottom view is expanded, when you push to start sharig your location it collapses, then if you stop sharing the bottomo view will expand again, I have no problem with this, I´ve already achive it, the problem here is when you tap into user's location and the marker show the callout because when the callout appears the bottom view expands again and it is supposed that it only expand or collapse when user share or stop sharing his location. I don't know why this is happening but I think is beacuse the callout makes the view hierarchy get lost. Please help me.

Here is all my code:

**MapViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import "UIView+HelperFunctions.h"
#import "BottomSheetViewController.h"
#import "BottomSheetDelegate.h"

@interface MapViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate, BottomSheetDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic) BOOL isUserSharingLocation;
@property (nonatomic, strong) MKMapView *mapView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *containerView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property BottomSheetViewController *bottomSheetVC;

- (void)shareUserLocation;
- (void)stopSharingUserLocation;

@end
```

**MapViewController.m**

```
#import "MapViewController.h"

@interface MapViewController ()

@end

@implementation MapViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.isUserSharingLocation = NO;
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [self.locationManager setDelegate:self];
    [self setupViewComponents];
    [self addBottomSheetView];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

}

- (void)setupViewComponents {
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.containerView];

    self.mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:self.mapView];

    [self.mapView topAnchor:self.view.topAnchor leftAnchor:self.view.leftAnchor bottomAchor:self.view.bottomAnchor rightAnchor:self.view.rightAnchor
                 topPadding:0 leftPadding:0 bottomPadding:0 rightPadding:0
                widthAnchor:0 heightAnchor:0];

}

- (void)addBottomSheetView {
    self.bottomSheetVC = [[BottomSheetViewController alloc] init];

    [self addChildViewController:self.bottomSheetVC];
    [self.view addSubview:[self.bottomSheetVC view]];
    [self.bottomSheetVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    [self.bottomSheetVC.view topAnchor:nil leftAnchor:self.view.leftAnchor bottomAchor:self.view.bottomAnchor rightAnchor:self.view.rightAnchor
                       topPadding:0 leftPadding:0 bottomPadding:0 rightPadding:0
                      widthAnchor:0 heightAnchor:200];

    [self.bottomSheetVC setDelegate:self];
}

- (void)shareUserLocation {
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingHeading];
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
}

- (void)stopSharingUserLocation {
    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    [self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:NO];
}

#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations {
    CLLocation *location = self.locationManager.location;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D currentLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude);
    [self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:currentLocation animated:YES];
    [self.mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
    [self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
    MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(currentLocation, 30000, 30000);
    [self.mapView setRegion:viewRegion];
}

#pragma mark - MKMapViewDelegate

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {
    [view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
}

#pragma mark - BottomSheetDelegate

- (void)shareUserLocation:(BOOL)shareLocation {
    if (shareLocation == YES) {
        [self shareUserLocation];
    } else {
        [self stopSharingUserLocation];
    }
}

- (void)hideBottomSheet:(BOOL)hide {
    if(hide == YES) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            CGRect frame = self.bottomSheetVC.view.frame;
            CGFloat y = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - 60;
            self.bottomSheetVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, y, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);
        }];
    } else {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            CGRect frame = self.bottomSheetVC.view.frame;
            CGFloat y = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - frame.size.height;
            self.bottomSheetVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, y, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);
        }];
    }
}

@end
```

**BottomSheetViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "UIView+HelperFunctions.h"
#import "BottomSheetDelegate.h"

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface BottomSheetViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic) id <BottomSheetDelegate> delegate;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

**BottomSheetViewController.m**

```
#import "BottomSheetViewController.h"

@interface BottomSheetViewController ()

@end

@implementation BottomSheetViewController

BOOL isExpanded = YES;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self setupViewComponents];
}

- (void)setupViewComponents {
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    UIButton *sendButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [self.view addSubview:sendButton];
    [sendButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"send_button_normal"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [sendButton addTarget:self action:@selector(handleSend) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [sendButton topAnchor:self.view.topAnchor leftAnchor:nil bottomAchor:nil rightAnchor:self.view.rightAnchor
               topPadding:8 leftPadding:0 bottomPadding:0 rightPadding:-8
              widthAnchor:40 heightAnchor:40];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:label];
    [label setText:@"Enviar ubicación en tiempo real"];
    [label setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]];
    [label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    [label centerYinView:sendButton];
    [[label.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.leftAnchor constant:8] setActive:YES];

    UIView *separatorLine = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:separatorLine];
    [separatorLine setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    [separatorLine topAnchor:sendButton.bottomAnchor leftAnchor:self.view.leftAnchor bottomAchor:nil rightAnchor:self.view.rightAnchor
                  topPadding:8 leftPadding:0 bottomPadding:0 rightPadding:0
                 widthAnchor:0 heightAnchor:1];
}

- (void)handleSend {
    NSLog(@"SEND");
    if (isExpanded == YES) {
        [self.delegate shareUserLocation:YES];
        [self.delegate hideBottomSheet:YES];
        isExpanded = !isExpanded;
    } else {
        [self.delegate shareUserLocation:NO];
        [self.delegate hideBottomSheet:NO];
        isExpanded = !isExpanded;
    }
}

@end
```

**BottomSheetDelegate.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@protocol BottomSheetDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)shareUserLocation:(BOOL)shareLocation;
- (void)hideBottomSheet:(BOOL)hide;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```